# Is it safe to install a heating duct register in the ceiling directly above a home entertainment center?

Tags: hvac, ducts

We're in the process of getting bids for central heating and one of the conundrums is where to position the registers.  Due to the layout of our living room (and style preferences of my significant other) we may have heating duct register about 2-3 feet directly above our flat panel TV.  Is this a safe practice? Generally speaking, can something like this damage our electronics?

Is there a recommended "safe distance" any/all electronics should be from a register?

Comment: Heat may not be the only issue. Constantly blowing dust/debris at the TV may not be so good either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HerrBag stated, heat and electronics don't get along well. Remember however, Your electronics will often run warmer than what your heating the house at and all electronics have a recommended temperature range for operating. I would encourage you to review the manual that came with your electronics.

For instance, the recommended operating temperature of my lcd tv is anywhere from 41 to 104 degrees Fahrenheit. In the summer we run the AC, in the winter we heat the house to 70. Now the TV itself will give off some heat, but not enough to bring moving 70 degree air up above 104 degrees.

I find that humidity is more of danger to electronics than heat or cold, but again read your manual.

Comment: The tolerance between your example of 104 to 70 is large enough where it doesn't matter but remember that you are not heating your house to 70 with 70 degree air. Your heater is pushing out air at it's optimal level (probably closer to 85) and heating your house under the thermostat registers the temperature to be 70. Maybe an easier example to notice is an electric stove or oven which you can see turn on @ 100% and power cycles on/off to maintain the heat level/temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Heat is electronics enemy.. If it's the only place, at least be sure to install a cover that can redirect (and reduce in volume) away from screen.